# Try catch nested in try catch, mongoose and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Is this solution correct? Can I do this with only one try catch, or does it have to be try catch nested in try catch, i'm working with express and mongoose for mongodb.

```
    try {
        const savedRoom = await newRoom.save()
        try {
            await Hotel.findByIdAndUpdate(hotelId, {$push : {rooms: savedRoom._id}})
        } catch (err) {
            next(err)
        }
        res.status(200).json(savedRoom);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err)
    }
```

I want to ask for the best solution.

Comment: Hotel.findByIdAndUpdate().then(()=>res.json(savedRoom)).catch(e=>res.status(500).json({error:e.msg}) could be shorter, you need to await to use try and catch but its included in promise system

Comment: so for every await, I need to use single try catch?

Comment: Use just one try/catch. The logic is the same for both successes and either failure.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `next(err)` doesn't exit the program, if line `await Hotel.findByIdAndUpdate(hotelId, {$push : {rooms: savedRoom._id}})` throws an exception, `res.status(200).json(savedRoom);` will be executed.
If you don't want this, a unique try catch would be better.